# C/C++ pointers as/in functions

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers

This is a very novice question, but I have noticed that some C-functions are of the form:

```
int* foo(int *N){...}
```

Can someone:

a) explain what the int* foo means? In one such function there is no 
`return` statement.

b) explain how flexible the int *N is? I.e., I know that this means that the argument is a pointer to an int, but from what I understand from looking at one such function, this means that the function foo can actually take vector arguments. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: I started answering, but I think for a) you really should learn the basics of C and/or C++. As for b), that is one of the danger-zones of C and C++: a pointer can represent so many different things. You can generally avoid this in C++ with better abstractions (mainly user defined types from the standard library.)

Comment: I have learned some C, but looking at a particular program has thrown a few things into question. In particular I never thought that "int * N" could mean that N* could be a vector argument. That is the main point.

The first question might be because I was given buggy code, but there is no return statement in similar code.

Comment: I have "The C Programming Language" book by Kernighan and Ritchie. It doesn't seem to cover this case.

Comment: Check out chapter 5. It's all about Pointers and Arrays.

Comment: OK, so you know that `int* foo();` is a function that returns a pointer to `int` but you want to know what that really means?

Comment: @Lepidopterist _In one such function there is no return statement._ really? Does it compile?
_can actually take vector arguments._ What do you even mean by that?

Comment: Generally pointers are returned when the address to something can be changed or allocated within the function. Consider a function that allocates an array of 100 `int`. In the function you might have `int *array = malloc (100 * sizeof *array);` The function may assign values to the array, etc. A function can only return a **single** value, so you cannot return the array as an `int`. But... you can return a pointer (pointing to the start of the memory address holding the array). So a function returning a pointer is just returning an address to the start of something.

Comment: Ok, I've been shamed into deleting this question.

Comment: Sometimes experts forget they once had been newbies ... The question is about basic concept, but WTF ... it's A PERFECTLY LEGITIMATE QUESTION the leads to very valuable answers the that will save a newbie from a lot of headache.  Donvoters ... calm dow a while! You should encourage people that wants to learn not slam the door in face. Shame on you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a) explain what the `int* foo` means? In one such function there is no `return` statement.

It means `foo` is a function that returns a pointer to an `int`. If such a function does not have a `return` statement, then calling that function will lead to undefined behavior.

From the C++ Standard:

> **6.6.3 The `return` statement**
>
> ...
>
> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

> b) explain how flexible the `int *N` is?

That depends on the implementation of `foo`. The following are syntactically valid ways to call `foo`. Whethe they are semantically valid depends on `foo`.

```
int a;
int b[10];
int* c = new int;
int* d = new int[20];

foo(&a);
foo(b);
foo(c);
foo(d);
foo(nullptr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the website is peer pressuring me into deleting it.

Comment: That's up to you. No worries.

Comment: @Lepidopterist: That's only a stuipid behavior of certain "expert" not remembering where their knowledge come from. They see a "simple question" and click "downvote", sometimes even without reading at all.

Your question and your accepted answer should be on the front page ow whatever serious publication about C or C++.

Don't pay attention to silly people. Just pass and go!

Answer (score 2):

`int* foo(int *N)` is a function that takes a pointer, this pointer points to at least one int, but possibly to an array of integers, C is a bit sloppy on this disiction.

```
{
   int n = 0;
   foo(&n);
}
```

or maybe

```
{
   int a[17];
   foo(a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my confusion. I think the other question might be due to buggy code. It is hard for me to explain the code, because it is someone else's private code and my question is motivated by my attempt to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, foo is a pointer to a function taking one argument, an integer pointer, and that returns int. It's as if you're declaring a function called "*foo", which takes an integer pointer and returns an interger; now, if *foo is a function, then foo must be a pointer to a function.

The key to writing the declaration for a function pointer is that you're just writing out the declaration of a function but with (*func_name) where you'd normally just put func_name.